# Spring vs Servlets

Tags: java, spring, развертывание, hosting

Доброго времени суток.

Перед мной выбор технологий для веб магазина Spring или Servlets + ко всему мне поручили зделать деплой на хостинг(самый дешовый).

Так как хостинг не будет "топ" я хочу выбрать самую "економическою" технологию.

И собственно вопрос: *Дешовый хостинг потянет Spring или будет лагать?*

П.С.
Я понимаю что в большей части ето зависит от написаного кода(кода будет относительно немного).

Comment: Я конечно не знаю наверняка, но мне кажется, самым дешевым, как с точки зрения разработки, так и с точки зрения аренды хостинга будет пыха )  А так сама по себе технология ни о чем не говорит. Лагать из-за чисто спринга точно не будет.

Comment: @Uraty Спасибо за ответ!)

Comment: Что спринг, что сервлеты  - одинаковая производительность, т.к и то , и другое - использует жвм, апликейшин сервер, контейнер сервлетов.

Comment: @aleshka-batman Оу, спасибо, ето все упрощает.

Comment: @aleshka-batman это почти то же самое, что сказать "и у 'Оки', и у 'Land Cruiser' есть руль и колёса, поэтому расход бензина у них одинаковый". Конечно, производительность будет выше, а потребление памяти ниже при использовании чистых сервлетов (если код, конечно, хороший пишете). Другой вопрос - насколько именно, и следует ли жертвовать скоростью и удобством разработки с помощью Spring ради этого выигрыша.

Comment: @fromSPb велика ли разница?